# window.open is opening a new tab with orgin/url

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that is located inside iframe with url="loclahost:3000" for example.

I have an event on this button that should open a new tab with another url for example "www.google.com". But when I click the button I am getting the new tab opened with the following url "http://localhost:3000/www.google.com"

I am using a window.open('www.google.com") function in order to open the new tab.

How can I remove the "http://localhost:3000/" from the new tab url?

Comment: Could you add your code please?

Comment: Did you try `https://www.google.com` ?

Comment: `window.open('www.google.com")` *Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token* you have single and double quotes mixed

Comment: Yes, the "http://" has solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do so would be to use an absolute link, which cancels out any relativity the URL might have:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com";

window.open(url);
```

Here the `https://` signifies it's a completely different page to the current page, so the browser should open that link, not try and find a file by that name.